# Navigate programmatically to a BottomNavigation tab

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen with Jetpack Compose that has a BottomNavigation and a NavHost.

At certain point, I return a certain value to that screen and its effect must be that it should navigate to one of the tabs.

If I just use `navController.navigate(destination)` then I have the following error:

> 2022-09-19 13:14:56.577 30826-30826/com.flingtheapp E/AndroidRuntime:
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.flingtheapp, PID: 30826
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1652)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1979)
> at tech.atlabs.fling.android.core.MainScreenKt.MainScreen(MainScreen.kt:70)
> at tech.atlabs.fling.android.ComposableSingletons$AppActivityKt$lambda-1$1$1$6.invoke(AppActivity.kt:66)
> at tech.atlabs.fling.android.ComposableSingletons$AppActivityKt$lambda-1$1$1$6.invoke(AppActivity.kt:65)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:163)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:60)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:162)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:115)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$4$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:110)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:124)
> at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:55)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:141)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown
> Source:13)
> at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown
> Source:10)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2363)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2630)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3217)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3195)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:336)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown
> Source:1)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3195)
> 2022-09-19 13:14:56.577 30826-30826/com.flingtheapp E/AndroidRuntime:
> at
> androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3160)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:748)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:876)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:485)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:454)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:997)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:728)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8154)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
> Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException:
> [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@56fece1,
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@1da9a06,
> StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@ba598c7, AndroidUiDispatcher@af8def4]
> 2022-09-19 13:14:56.621 30826-30826/com.flingtheapp I/Process: Sending
> signal. PID: 30826 SIG: 9 2022-09-19 13:14:58.738 31683-31683/?
> E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted 2022-09-19
> 13:14:58.738 31683-31683/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1 2022-09-19
> 13:14:58.742 31683-31683/? I/com.flingtheap: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
> 2022-09-19 13:14:58.764 31683-31683/? E/com.flingtheap: Unknown bits
> set in runtime_flags: 0x8000 2022-09-19 13:14:58.773 31683-31683/?
> D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator 2022-09-19 13:14:58.773
> 31683-31683/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put 2022-09-19
> 13:15:02.809 31683-31683/com.flingtheapp I/FirebaseApp: Device
> unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT] 2022-09-19
> 13:15:02.922 31683-31683/com.flingtheapp I/FirebaseInitProvider:
> FirebaseApp initialization successful 2022-09-19 13:15:03.000
> 31683-31683/com.flingtheapp I/[Koin]: [init] declare Android Context
> 2022-09-19 13:15:03.092 31683-31683/com.flingtheapp I/[Koin]: loaded
> 31 definitions - 1.26177 ms 2022-09-19 13:15:03.092
> 31683-31683/com.flingtheapp I/[Koin]: create eager instances ...
> 2022-09-19 13:15:08.308 31683-31722/com.flingtheapp
> D/ProfileInstaller: Installing profile for com.flingtheapp

So I guess that this is not the correct way to do it.

How can I programmatically navigate using NavController?

===

EDIT: Code that fails:

const val MAIN_COMPOSABLE_ID = "main"

```
sealed class MainTabNavigation(
    val route: String,
    @StringRes val resourceId: Int,
    @DrawableRes val drawableId: Int
) {
    object Tab1 : MainTabNavigation("tab1", R.string.shop_tabName, R.drawable.tab1)
    object Tab2 :
        MainTabNavigation("tab2", R.string.wardrobe_tabName, R.drawable.tab2)

    object Tab3 : MainTabNavigation("tab3", R.string.cart_tabName, R.drawable.tab3)
    object Tab4 : MainTabNavigation("tab4", R.string.profile_tabName, R.drawable.tab4)
}

private val navItems = listOf(
    MainTabNavigation.Tab1, MainTabNavigation.Tab2,
    MainTabNavigation.Tab3, MainTabNavigation.Tab4
)

@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController) {
    val mainNavController = rememberNavController()

    var goToTab2 = false

    val commManager by inject<ComposableCommManager>()
    val comm = commManager.readComm(MAIN_COMPOSABLE_ID)
    comm?.let {
        if (it.communication == "go_to_tab2") {
            goToTab2 = true
        }
    }

    if (goToTab2) {
        // TODO This line fails
        mainNavController.navigate(MainTabNavigation.Tab3.route)
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding(),
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigation(
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
            ) {
                val navBackStackEntry by mainNavController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

                navItems.forEach { tab ->
                    BottomNavigationItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                painterResource(id = tab.drawableId),
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        },
                        label = { Text(stringResource(tab.resourceId)) },
                        alwaysShowLabel = false,
                        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == tab.route } == true,
                        onClick = {
                            mainNavController.navigate(tab.route) {
                                popUpTo(mainNavController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                                    saveState = true
                                }
                                launchSingleTop = true
                                restoreState = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            mainNavController,
            startDestination = if (goToTab2) {
                MainTabNavigation.Tab3.route
            } else {
                startMainDestination
            },
            Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            composable(MainTabNavigation.Tab1.route) {
                ShopTab(navController)
            }
            composable(MainTabNavigation.Tab2.route) {
                WardrobeTab(navController, mainNavController)
            }
            composable(MainTabNavigation.Tab3.route) {
                CartTab(navController, mainNavController)
            }
            composable(MainTabNavigation.Tab4.route) {
                ProfileTab(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post you navcontroller and navhost as well ?

Comment: @JosefM I have added the code that fails.

Comment: alright, perfect! @svprdga

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (goToTab2) {
    mainNavController.navigate(MainTabNavigation.Tab3.route)
}
```

In jetpack Compose you can't use code like this, cause every time in recomposion that code will rerun. You have to put that part to clickable.
Or put your code with "command reading"  to view model, and in every ON_RESUME, check that value.

Or read that value in ON_RESUME block (but viewModel will be better).

```
@Composable
fun OnLifecycleEvent(onEvent: (owner: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) -> Unit) {
    val eventHandler = rememberUpdatedState(onEvent)
    val lifecycleOwner = rememberUpdatedState(LocalLifecycleOwner.current)

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner.value) {
        val lifecycle = lifecycleOwner.value.lifecycle
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { owner, event ->
            eventHandler.value(owner, event)
        }

        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
        onDispose {
            lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

use it like this

```
OnLifecycleEvent { _, event ->
    when (event) {
        Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
            mainPageViewModel.setEvent(MainPageContract.Event.OnResume)
        }
        else -> Unit
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this approach and it is not working. Altough the navigate() method is being called and no error is thrown, it isn't performing the navigation that I require.

Comment: your main mistake is if "(goToTab2) { mainNavController.navigate(MainTabNavigation.Tab3.route}". Don't use that logic in compose

Comment: All right, got it, now the question is: how to achieve what I want?